# How did the Bloody Girl die?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

Warning, this question is about some very end game content and contains spoilers!

How does the Bloody Girl die? The fire was set in the mansion, but as far as I understand, she was in the back house. Everybody else was in the mansion, and that's why they died.

> Except for Lucas, who jumps from the clocktower and survives. The Bloody girl is the pregnant wife of Lucas, that was awaiting for their baby in the back house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's deliberately ambiguous.**

It's not made clear exactly how she died, only that she died before her child was born.

However, given that she's the only person whos death Lucas doesn't torment himself over, it's likely she died after the fire.